# Pyhook UTF-8 issue

Tags: python, utf-8, pyhook

I'm making a python app that triggers an action when the print screen key is pressed. I'm using pyhook library. However, every time I press a character written with the language of my country (ãíé and others) is doubling the characters . For example : ~~a ''e ''i , causing problems in the normal user written use. Is there any way to fix ?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: So you react to the print screen button, what does that have to do with other characters?

Comment: pyhook is monitoring key events.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested method: use `pygame` module instead of `pythoncom` for pump events

```py
hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
# Dont use pythoncom.PumpMessages()

pygame.init()
while True:
    pygame.event.pump()
```

Old method: try to change **preferred language** and switch it back (just **toggle**), it may help.

For ex:

- Add one more language pack (not keyboard layout, input type **same**)
- Change preferred language
- Switch back to old one (that you are using)
- Switch back again if doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

try to add this line:

# -* - coding: utf-8 -* -